# nginx does not listen to pgadmin on docker on port other than 80

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, devops, pgadmin

There are several projects running on my server and I can not use port 80.
In this Docker, everything works fine except Pgadmin. No matter how much I change the code, I either get a 502 error or a 404 error in <SERVER_IP>:8090/pgadmin/

Can anyone guide me?

> nginx.conf :

```
upstream app_server {
server gis_app:8095;
}
upstream pg_server {
    server gis_pgadmin:5555;
}

server {
    listen 8090;
    server_name localhost;
    client_max_body_size 200M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /srv/gis/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /srv/gis/media/;
    }

    location /pgadmin/ {
        proxy_pass http://pg_server;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

> docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  gis_app:
    container_name: gis_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/gis/src
      - gis_static_volume:/srv/gis/static
      - gis_media_volume:/srv/gis/media
    networks:
      - gis_nginx_network
      - gis_db_network
      - gis_redis_network
    depends_on:
      - gis_db
      - gis_redis

  gis_nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: gis_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - gis_static_volume:/srv/gis/static
      - gis_media_volume:/srv/gis/media
    depends_on:
      - gis_app
    networks:
      - gis_nginx_network

  gis_db:
    image: kartoza/postgis
    container_name: gis_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - config/.env
    networks:
      - gis_db_network
    volumes:
      - gis_db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql

  gis_pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: gis_pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - gis_db
    ports:
    - 5555:8090
    networks:
      - gis_db_network
      - gis_nginx_network
    env_file:
      - config/.env


  gis_redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: gis_redis
    command: >
      --requirepass password
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - gis_redis_network

networks:
  gis_nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
  gis_db_network:
    driver: bridge
  gis_redis_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  gis_static_volume:
  gis_media_volume:
  gis_db_volume:
```

> and pgadmin env :

```
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=mail@info.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password
PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5555
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of `PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5555` is listening on port `5555`

So `gis_pgadmin` container should listen on that port `5555`

Nginx will be forwarded from `8090` --> `5555`

```
gis_pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: gis_pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - gis_db
    ports:
    - 5555:5555
```

Comment: I also tried ports 5555:5555, 5555:8090, 5555:80  and 5 but it didn't work.
docker ps :
gis_pgadmin   /entrypoint.sh                   Up      443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, 80/tcp

Comment: on the host, did you check port 5555 for `gis_pgadmin` work or not ?

Comment: using `curl ip_address_of_pgadmin 5555` and check return back !

Comment: on localhost:5555 is work but now work on server, of course I want it to run on ip:8090/pgadmin/